# save .trace file to a different location

Tags: instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm running instruments from command line. In my command, i did specified the output path 
using

```
-e UIARESULTSPATH /user/xxxx
```

However, the files saved to the location above are plist liles. the .trace (ie. instrumentscli14.trace)  files are automatically saved to the folder i save my scripts.

Do anyone know is there a way to save the .trace files to a custom location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Do anyone know is there a way to save the .trace files to a custom
>   location?

Use the `-D` option, like this:

```
-D TestResults/TestTrace/theTrace.trace
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that -D option is not working, but instruments saves trace file to current directory where you run command from..

Comment: I've found that if I put the -D directly after the instruments command it works. If I put -D after the UIASCRIPT variable, it does not work.